# Using a BASH script to read the output displayed in console from a third source?

Tags: bash, scripting, read, syntax

I am having issues understanding how to get `read` to "read" information from the console instead of user input. Effectively "getline"? from console.

Here is my scenario. I will be sending an `echo "information" | ncat "IP" "PORT"` to a port located internally on the network running a deamon to catch correct information.

If information I send is incorrect I will be sent a predefined message telling me that the information sent was incorrect and to try again. However, if the information is correct, I will get a different response from which I have no idea what the response will be.

Here is a snippet of the BASH script I have tried so far.

```
if [[read -r line ; echo "$line" ; while "$line" == "Information wrong try again!"]] ; continue
elif [[read -r line ; echo "$line" ; while "$line" != "Information wrong try again!"]] ;break
```

I am very new to bash, so my use of my syntax may be incorrect.

Comment: Please read a basic guide to bash so you can learn the syntax of the language. You seem to be just guessing here and that will only make your life harder.

Comment: Understood, I have been to learn via examples and using google fu and sites like stack exchange to learn. :) I am trying honestly :D.  Will reread basic guide now, let me grab a coffee. But all suggestions and advice still welcome.

Comment: Yeah, learning with examples is great but only after you have understood the basic syntax. So first start with a basic tutorial and then go for the examples. You won't get far if you just try random syntax hoping it will work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your syntax is all wrong. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
if [ "$line" = "Information wrong try again!" ]; then
  echo "Try again"
else
    echo "All's well"
fi
```

Of course, the details will depend on how you run the script. If you want it to be an infinite loop and re-run the `echo "information" | ncat "IP" "PORT"` command until it works, you want something like this:

```
line=$(echo "information" | ncat "IP" "PORT")
while [ "$line" = "Information wrong try again!" ]; do
    line=$(echo "information" | ncat "IP" "PORT")
    sleep 1 ## wait one second between launches to avoid spamming the CPU
done

## At this point, we have gotten a value of `$line` that is not `Information wrong try again!`, so we can continue. 
echo "Worked!"
```

Or, similarly:

```
while [ $(echo "information" | ncat "IP" "PORT") = "Information wrong try again!" ]; do
    sleep 1 ## wait one second between launches to avoid spamming the CPU
done

## rest of the script goes here
echo "Worked!"
```